# Not able to use the right python interpreter in the output pane in VS Code

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

1) I installed Python3.7.3 on my Mac osx and confirmed this with the terminal (using 'python3 --version').

2) Then I selected the 3.7.3 interpreter in vs code. I can see that this interpreter is the one being used in the status bar at the bottom.

3) The debug console shows that I'm running Python3.7.3 when I run the following bits of code by pressing F5 inside VS-Code to start the code in the debugger. I can also run it right from the terminal with no issue (python3 app.py).

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

```
variable = "awesome"
print(f"Today is {variable}")
```

#### The Problem:

4) When I try print(sys.version) the "Output" pane is still showing that I'm running Python2.7.10.

When I try to use an f string I see a syntax error in the output pane... the terminal and debug console both are able to print the string as intended.

How can I make my output pane interpret python3.7 instead of 2.7? I'm thinking there will be something I need to do in a settings.json file but I'm not sure where to start.

Here is all of my launch.json file. I think this is relevant?

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "enter-your-module-name-here",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my global settings.json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
}
```

This is my workspace.json:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "/Users/sethgory/Desktop/school/CPSC50100/Python/Week01"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

Here is the output when I try to use an f-string:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/sethgory/Desktop/school/CPSC50100/Python/Week01/Hello.py"
  File "/Users/sethgory/Desktop/school/CPSC50100/Python/Week01/Hello.py", line 5
    print(f"Today is {variable}")
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.909 seconds
```

Here is output when I run print(sys.version):

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/sethgory/Desktop/school/CPSC50100/Python/Week01/Hello.py"
2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 2.421 seconds
```

When I press F5 to debug, this is what comes out in the debug console (running print(sys.version) again):

```
3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
:undefined
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

This is what I get in the terminal when debugging (running print(sys.version) again):

```
Week01 sethgory$ cd /Users/sethgory/Desktop/school/CPSC50100/Python/Week01 ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/sethgory/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.3.6139/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 55179 /Users/sethgory/Desktop/school/CPSC50100/Python/Week01/Hello.py 
3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

And finally, when I run the program from the terminal using "python3 Hello.py", this is what I get there (running print(sys.version) again):

```
3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

#### Some things I've tried so far:

I have tried to use the following three paths (one at a time!) in both the global and workspace settings and none seem to change the behavior at all:

This is absolute, I think:

```
{
        "python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3"
    }
```

This is absolute to the env folder:

```
{
        "python.pythonPath": "/Users/sethgory/Desktop/school/CPSC50100/Python/Week01/env/bin/python3"
    }
```

This is relative to the env folder:

```
{
        "python.pythonPath": "env/bin/python3"
    }
```

I have tried to add `alias python='python3'` to my ~/.bash_profile and got some new behavior in the terminal. Now I can use "python" to reference python3 (whereas before I needed to actually type the "3". But the main issue remains (output window in vs code still using python2.7.2)

```
Seth-Gorys-MacBook-Pro:~ sethgory$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
Seth-Gorys-MacBook-Pro:~ sethgory$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

I should mention that I do have the Python extension properly installed. And the correct interpreter 3.7.3 is showing up in the status bar.

Comment: The problem is possibly caused by your IDE setup. Without knowing what exactly you changed and how it is impossible to tell. First thing I'd look at is the debugger settings though. If that doesn't give you a hint, you will have to provide precise steps for reproducing the issue, similar to a [mcve].

Comment: To give you an advice about running python code within vscode, i personally prefer to just open a terminal tab and run `py filename` as it's much faster and much more convenient

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, From scratch: install latest version of vs code, install latest version of python3, run the minimal code I provided, view the discrepancy in interpreter usage from output pane to terminal/debug console. I want to share my json settings for this but I'm not finding specific settings for the output pane. I just added some of my settings.json to help

Comment: "run the minimal code" -- how exactly? Note the distinction between your intention and the actual actions. If in doubt, provide both (e.g. "Press F5 inside VS-Code to start the code in the debugger"). Also, [edit] your question to include those steps.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for guiding me to be more specific.

Comment: The `launch.json` looks fine. What is your `settings.json` (both global and for the workspace)?

Comment: And what is showing up in the terminal when the debugger launches? There should be a long command specifying how the debugger is started.

Comment: @BrettCannon I have updated my question to include all of that now. Let me know if more info would help.

Comment: @serGor do you have  "python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3" in VsCode workspace folder,your setting is relative and not absolute path.

Comment: @serGor basically this makes no sense and you seem to unfortunately be the only person on the planet having such a problem. :) Please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python